# Python MYSQL dynamic variables error with SQL syntax

Tags: python, mysql

I wrote below function:

```
def update_record(col, new_value, date, finance_manager_table, connection):
    finance_manager_table.execute("""
       UPDATE financemanager
       SET %s = %s
       WHERE Date = %s
    """, (col, new_value, date))
    connection.commit()
```

Then I try to call the function with:
`dbc.update_record("Salary", "2500", "January/22", finance_manager_table, connection)`
and then experiencing the error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Salary' = 2500
> WHERE Date = 'January/22'' at line 2

So it looks as it creates correct statement, but still somehow wrong.

I've removed 'col' and instead wrote "SET Salary = %s" which has worked.

Is it incorrect to write "SET %s = %s", or is there a problem with something else?

Thanks!
Adam

Comment: the root cause of this issue is that parametrization has not ever supported table nor column-name string substitution. usually the way i would suggest this to be done is in two steps: 1) perform the string substition for the column name only in your case, then 2) pass that newly constructed query and the parameters to `.execute()`. There are a ton of other SO questions and answers about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Python 3's f-Strings: An Improved String Formatting Syntax

```
s = f"""
       UPDATE financemanager
       SET {col} = {new_value}
       WHERE Date = '{date}'
    """
finance_manager_table.execute(s)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this way of writing dynamic variables into a string. Worked perfectly!

Comment: please upvote if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one of Python's string formatting methods(f-string, .format) for the database object names(tables, columns, etc.) also a good idea to wrap them in backticks and use `%s` substitution of the .execute() method for values to prevent SQL injection:

```py
def update_record(col, new_value, date, finance_manager_table, connection):
    finance_manager_table.execute(f"""
       UPDATE financemanager
       SET `{col}` = %s
       WHERE Date = %s
    """, (new_value, date))
    connection.commit()
```

or

```py
def update_record(col, new_value, date, finance_manager_table, connection):
    finance_manager_table.execute("""
       UPDATE financemanager
       SET `{}` = %s
       WHERE Date = %s
    """.format(col), (new_value, date))
    connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you were getting an error was because in the part of your query `SET %s = %s`, the first variable you were passing in was being interpreted as a string so it was surrounding it in single quotes. This was causing it not to be recognized as a column name. In other words it was turning that part of the query into `SET 'Salary' = 2500`